# getting the value from xml feed in android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, arraylist, domparser

I have developing one android application.

i have passing the xml tags.

Here i have facing some problems.please give me a solution for these .

These is my xml feed :

```
   <root>
    <Categories>
    <Category title="books" categoryid="1" image="http://google.com/dsdsds.png" >
    <SubCategory>
     <Subcategory name="Android" subcategoryid="2" subimage="http://google.comdsdsdsd.jpg" >
    <Products>
    <product name="android programming" productid="3" >
       <Retailers>
      <Retailer name='sfsdsds' />
       <Retailer name='sdsdsdsd' />
        </Retailers>
```

Here i have passing the retailer uisng the below code:

```
    if (productNode
                                                            .hasChildNodes()) {
                                                          NodeList retailerNameNL = productElmt
                                                                .getElementsByTagName("Retailers");
                                                                if (retailerNameNL.getLength() > 0) {
                                                                    for (int rnCnt = 0; rnCnt < retailerNameNL
                                                                            .getLength(); rnCnt++) {
                                                                        Node retailerNameNode = retailerNameNL
                                                                                .item(rnCnt);
                                                                    if (retailerNameNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                                                                        Element retailernamesElmt = (Element) retailerNameNode;
                                                                        NodeList retailernamesChildNL = retailernamesElmt
                                                                                .getElementsByTagName("Retailer");
                                                                        if (retailernamesChildNL.getLength() > 0) {
                                                                            RetailerNameAL = new ArrayList<RetailerNames>();
                                                                            for (int rnIdx = 0; rnIdx < retailernamesChildNL
                                                                                    .getLength(); rnIdx++) {
                                                                                Node retailernamesChildNode = retailernamesChildNL
                                                                                        .item(rnIdx);
                                                                                RetailerNames retailernamesBean = null;
                                                                                Element retailernamesChildElmt = null;
                                                                                if (retailernamesChildNode
                                                                                        .hasAttributes()) {
                                                                                    retailernamesBean = new RetailerNames();
                                                                                    retailernamesChildElmt = (Element) retailernamesChildNode;
                                                                                    retailernamesBean
                                                                                            .setmProductType(retailernamesChildElmt
                                                                                                    .getAttribute("name"));
                                                                            RetailerNameAL
                                                                                .add(retailernamesBean);
```

Here i am getting the list of retailer names depends upon selected productid.

**my query is :**

i have to pass these list of name to another one activity depends upon the productid.

```
        List<String> shoplist = new ArrayList<String>();
                    shoplist.add(product.getString(TAG_SHOP));
                    shoplist.addAll(HomePage.retailerNameBean
                            .getmProductType()
                            + ",");

     ArrayAdapter<String> shopadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EditWatchListProducts.this,
                                          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, shoplist);
```

But am getting the first item correctly.afterthat am getting the empty item on that list:

pls give me the solution for these ... how can i get the Retailername list on that arraylist depands upon seletcted category.

Comment: Do you have any url for the xml data...

Comment: like this https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?ctype=xml&id=54996 do you have any url or your giving xml as string

Comment: @Hari i have using below url(like string) : xml = getXmlFromUrl("http://xxx.com/feed.xml");

Comment: @user2218667 what is that you actually need, Values stored in XML file..??

Answer (score 0):

Try This Codes...

```
    import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class XMLParsingDOMExample extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> description;

    ItemAdapter adapter1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        description = new ArrayList<String>();  

        try {

            URL url = new URL(Your URL);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         
                Log.v("title--", ""+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                title.add(""+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("description");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
                Log.v("description--", ""+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());            
                description.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());   

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        adapter1 = new ItemAdapter(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }


    class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView title_text;
            public TextView des_text;

        }

        public ItemAdapter(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super();
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
        }

        //@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return title.size();
        }

        //@Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //@Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mainpage_listitem_activity, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
                holder.des_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.des_text);


                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            holder.title_text.setText(""+title.get(position));


            holder.des_text.setText(""+Html.fromHtml(description.get(position)));


        return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of item use Retailers and Instead of title & description use Retailername

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to get values from the XML File

My XML Files with values that i want to take, File name is Version.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" 
      "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="Version" class="com.XXX.domain.web.permissions.Version">
        <property name="Version" value="2013061101"></property>
        <property name="Release" value="0.5"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Now I need a Bean Class to Map the values in the XML, Named as Version in the package 
com.XXX.domain.web.permissions

It Contains the following Code

```
package com.XXX.domain.web.permissions;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;


public class Version {

    private String Version;
    private String Release;
    public Version() {

    }
    public String getVersion() {
        return Version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        Version = version;
    }

    public String getRelease() {
        return Release;
    }

    public void setRelease(String release) {
        Release = release;
    }

}
```

Now the XML maps the values to the Bean Class and You can get the values from where ever you want using this.

```
ApplicationContext getBean= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/Version.xml");
    Version ver=(Version)getBean.getBean("Version");
    return ver.getRelease();
```